# Call Web API from View with parameters from dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Today I have a Web Api like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    NameValueCollection nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.RequestUri.Query, Encoding.UTF8);
    string Report = nvc["Report"].ToString();
    Int64 Id = Convert.ToInt64(nvc["Id"]);
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    switch (Report)
    {
        case "PackLista":
            response.Content = new StreamContent(this.PackLista(Id));
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
            break;
    }
    return response;
}
```

For test I use javascript to call this API with a button and hardcoded parameter like this:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Index", "Meels", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-3">                    
                <label class="control-label ">Choose:</label>
                 @Html.DropDownList("SearchString", (IList<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Htos, "-- All --", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input  value="Report" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="cmdPrint_onclick()"/>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
}

<script>
    function cmdPrint_onclick() 
    {
            // 
            window.location.href = '/api/Report/Report?report=PackLista&Id=2' ;
    }

</script>
```

Now I want to use the value from the dropdown list as parameter `Id` in the javascript. Or perhaps jQuery is the right way? How can I do this?
As you see the return from API is stream in pdf format so the result opens a pdf-document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `JS version is` [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7q50wsLu/1/)
2. `jQuery way to do this is` [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pccuuLrq/1/)

The difference is only in the script we use to get selected value of the dropdown.